# unBind a bound service

Tags: android, service, ipc

I've a bound service that runs in separate process

```
public class DownloadService extends Service {

private Looper mLooper;
private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

private Messenger messenger;
private Messenger uiMessenger;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
            Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND);
    thread.start();

    mLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mLooper);

    messenger = new Messenger(mServiceHandler);
}

private class ServiceHandler extends Handler {

    public ServiceHandler() {

    }

    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {

        case MSG_DOWNLOAD_REQUEST:

            String url = msg.getData().getString("url");

            Log.d("test", url);

            // download(url);

            break;

        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    Log.d("test", "onBind");

    return messenger.getBinder();
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("test", "onRebind");
    super.onRebind(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

    Log.d("test", "onUnbind");

    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Log.d("test", "onDestroy");

    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

And also a ServiceConnection like this:

```
serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

                serviceMessenger = null;
                isConnected = false;

                Log.d("test", "disconn");
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
                    IBinder service) {

                if (serviceMessenger == null) {

                    serviceMessenger = new Messenger(service);
                }

                isConnected = true;

                Log.d("test", "conn");

                send();
            }
        };
```

Request for bind to service

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DownloadService.class);
        context.bindService(intent, serviceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

And unBind request

```
        context.unbindService(serviceConnection);
```

Once a call bindService every thing is good and work properly and `onServiceConnected` method of `ServiceConnection` invoked, but when I call `unBind` method `onServiceDisconnected` is not called! while `onUnbind` and `onDestroy` methods of service are invoked.

And more surprisingly, I can communicate with service using `serviceMessenger` that made in previous `bind`!

**Summary**
1. Why `onServiceDisconnected` not invoked when I call `unBind` method?
2- Why it is possible to communicate with a service that destroyed due to `unBind` call?

Comment: ad 1: "Called when a connection to the Service has been lost. This typically happens when the process hosting the service has crashed or been killed. This does not remove the ServiceConnection itself -- this binding to the service will remain active, and you will receive a call to onServiceConnected(ComponentName, IBinder) when the Service is next running." in short it is not used as a callback of `unbindService` method call

Comment: `This typically happens when the process hosting the service has crashed or been killed.` When this happens, Which methods of service, called?

Comment: the best way is to override some Service's methods and add some `Log.d` inside

Comment: Already I do that. just `onBind` is invoked.

Comment: When the process is killed none of the methods from components gets called. May be it is the binder I service manager framework that invokes onServiceDiscoonected method on the clients.

Comment: ok, seems that i am not sure what actually is your problem, whats your point?

Comment: @pskink I've read a lot about services and threads but I think I'm still a beginner. I do not have any idea. Just Thanks

Comment: so what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @7383 I think that my service is not killed because I can communicate with that several times without any problems.

Comment: hint: see http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java and ^F mServiceLooper

Comment: @pskink `so what do you want to achieve?`I apologize for my poor English language. If you mean what I want to do, I'll done more searches and try to find a way :)

Comment: @Mousa Jafari The service is killed by os but since you hold the reference to the service object may be it is not garbage collected and hence you would be still able to invoke calls on that object. It is a memory leak as it is not recommended to hold these objects even after your onServiceDisconnected method is called.

Comment: Thanks @7383. But why it should be killed? May you help to solve my problem? my service source code is mentioned above.

Comment: @Mousa Jafari I did not understand your issue here. Are you concerned about why onServiceDisconnected() is not invoked on calling unBind()?If so it is already answered. If you are talking about the second issue that is even after calling unBind() you are able to access the methods of service? If so, it is not recommended to do it, as soon as you unBind the service you must nullify your service objects in your activity. Hope i am clear.

Comment: @Mouse Jafari I think you should stop handler thread in your onUnBind() method in your service. After modifying it, please check you are still be able to access methods? Sorry for multiple comments.

Comment: @MousaJafari again see: http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java and ^F mServiceLooper

Comment: @7383 After stopping thread on `unBind` methods become unavailable. @7383 Still I want to know what should I do to `onServiceDisconnected()` be invoked? I need to notify when service is unbinded.

Comment: @Mouse Jafari Following the documentation it is called only when os kills the service process and if any clients are bounded. But in this case if you want to notify that your activity is unbinded to the service, you should deliberately either invoke onServiceDisconnected() or send a notifcation directly after unBindservice is called. Please mark my comments as useful if it helped you.

Comment: @pskink I've successfuly implemented services that starts by `startService` before. now I want to implement a bound service

Comment: "I need to notify when service is unbinded" why? this is your client that call `unbindService()` after that call you can assume your client is no longer bound

Comment: ok so what problem do you have with bound service?

Comment: @pskink Just I want to know why onServiceDisconnected() is not invoked

Comment: @7383 May you share documentation link? please

Comment: i think that i already answered that: onServiceDisconnected has nothing to do with unbindService

Comment: Sorry dears, I thought that invoking `unBind` method should make up invoke `onServiceDisconnected` method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html